# Java Applet to Multi Panel Application

Tags: java, applet, window, panel

I have made a Java game, but it is applet based. I want to convert it into a standalone application. Unfortunately I have 0 knowledge of swing/java applications so I'm not exactly sure where to start and how to get what I want.

My main issue is that the game screen is essentially divided into two parts. The "game screen" and what I refer to as the "dashboard". If you can imagine age of empires, star craft, or any other RTS type of game, that's what the layout is.

So what I want is the screen to have its own graphics panel (all the drawing/animation is done with the graphics and image class) that also has scroll bars in it, that way the size of the game isn't limited to the size of your screen. And I want the dashboard to be it's own separate independent panel, which also uses graphics methods. But in the end, both panels are in the same window.

Is there anyway this is possible?

PS: feel free to request any code or screenshots of the game

Edit: if it is possible, how should I go about doing this?

Comment: *"Is there anyway this is possible?"*  Any GUI layout that is possible in an applet is possible in a desk-top app., so the answer to your one question is..  ***Yes.***  Should I enter that as the answer, or do you want to ask a *more specific question?*

Comment: The more specific question is how I would go about doing this? Mersenne seems to give a pretty good answer, but I'm interested in seeing if you would answer different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Swing applications usually based on `JFrame` class. As i understand, whole game is rendered and not using standard components in UI. Then, roughly, almost no difference between `JApplet` and `JFrame` classes. If you used specific JApplet methods for loading resources or something similar, almost all of them would easily replaced with counterparts.

You could create a component class (by extending `JComponent`) and use it to render main game window. And create another one to render dashboard. Then use `BorderLayout` as layout manager on `JFrame`, place main window on center and dashboard on any edge.

There are pretty clear HowTo`s on Oracle site:
[How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) and [How to Use Panels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think Mersenne's answer covers it pretty well, though I'd consider rendering the game play in a `BufferedImage` and adding that to (an `ImageIcon` in) a `JLabel` in a `JScrollPane`.